# Conditional statement within loop using multiple datasets R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to figure out who was the **most recent previous owner** at a location within the last two years before the current owner. The locations are called `reflo` (reference location). *Note that there is not always an exact match for `reflo.x` and `reflo` within two years (so a solution that allows me to add additional conditions, such as to find the next closest `reflo`, would be extra helpful).*

**The conditions:**

- the previous owner has to have lived at the same location (`lifetime_census$reflo==owners$reflo.x[i]`) within two years of the current owner's year (`lifetime_census$census_year` <= 2 years of `owners$spr_census`)
- if none, then assign `NA`

Previous owners (>20,000) are stored in a dataset called `lifetime_census`. Here is a sample of the data:

```
id    previous_id      reflo  census_year 
16161 5587            -310     2001   
17723 5587            -310     2002      
19345 5879            -310     2003    
16848 5101             Q1      2001         
17836 6501             Q1      2002      
19439 6501             Q1      2003      
21815 6057             Q1      2004
```

I then have an `owners` dataset (here is a sample):

```
squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x 
6391        2005        Q1 
6130        2005       -310
6288        2005        A12
```

**To illustrate what I am trying to achieve:**

```
squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x  previous_owner  census_year
6391              2005  Q1      6057            2004
6130              2005 -310     5879            2003
6288              2005  A12     NA              NA
```

What I have currently tried is this:

```
n <- length(owners$squirrel_id)

for(i in 1:n) {
  last_owner <- subset(lifetime_census,
    life_census$previous_id!=owners$squirrel_id[i] & #previous owner != current owner
    lifetime_census$reflo==owners$reflo.x[i] &
    lifetime_census$census_year<=owners$spr_census[i])  #owners can be in current or past year

    #Put it all together
    owners[i,"spring_owner"] <- last_owner$previous_id[i]
}
```

This gives me a new column for the previous owner in **any** past year for `reflo.x`, adding NAs after all the conditions are not met. **I cannot figure out how to restrict this search to the last two years.**

Any ideas? (*Note that there is not always an exact match for `reflo.x` and `reflo` within two years (so a solution that allows me to add additional conditions, such as to find the next closest `reflo`, would be extra helpful).*)

Comment: One idea might be to join the two datasets on squirrel_id and then filter out all rows where the census year isn't within two years of spr_census.

Comment: If I joined them by `squirrel_id`, I would only show cases where the previous owner was the same owner as the current owner. I am trying to find the previous owner (that isn't the current owner).

Comment: I misunderstood the id variable, but a joining approach using whatever variable represents the property id is likely how I'd tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out who was the most recent previous owner at a location within the last two years before the current owner you can first **arrange by date in descending order**:

```
library(dplyr)
lifetime_census<-lifetime_census %>% 
       group_by(reflo) %>%  
       arrange(desc(census_date))
```

Which puts the most recent years first (similar to `top_n`):

```
id    previous_owner   reflo  census_year 
19345 5879            -310     2003  
17723 5587            -310     2002      
16161 5587            -310     2001   
21815 6057             Q1      2004 
19439 6501             Q1      2003      
17836 6501             Q1      2002      
16848 5101             Q1      2001
```

Then you can run the loop above:

```
n <- length(owners$squirrel_id)

for(i in 1:n) {
  last_owner <- subset(lifetime_census,
    life_census$squirrel_id != owners$squirrel_id[i] & 
    lifetime_census$reflo==owners$reflo.x[i] &
    lifetime_census$census_year <= owners$spr_census[i])  #owners can be in current or past year

    #Put it all together
    owners[i,"previous_owner"] <- last_owner$previous_owner[i]
    owners[i,"prev_census"] <- last_owner$census_year[i]
}
```

This will give you:

```
> head(owners)

> squirrel_id spr_census reflo.x  previous_owner  prev_census
  <chr>       <chr>      <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
  6391        2005       Q1       6057            2004
  6130        2005       -310     5879            2003
  6288        2005       A12      <NA>            <NA>
```

If, for example, an individual above had a match for a year <= 2 years from the `spr_census` year, you can fix this on a case by case basis (not the most elegant solution, but it's workable) by using an `if_else` statement, like so:

```
owners<-owners%>% mutate(spring_owner=ifelse(prev_census < 2003, "<NA>", spring_owner))
```